# Direct Sum of Quotient Modules and SES

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need a $\phi$ and a $\psi$ so that
$$
 0\rightarrow M^\prime/M^{\prime\prime}\stackrel{\phi}{\rightarrow} M/M^{\prime\prime}\stackrel{\psi}{\rightarrow}{M/M^{\prime}}\rightarrow 0
$$ is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules where $M^{\prime\prime}\le M^{\prime}\le M$ and $M/M^{\prime\prime}$ is a torsion module.  Now, if $M/M^{\prime\prime}=M^{\prime}/M^{\prime\prime}\bigoplus M/M^{\prime}$ then I could just use an injective map for $\phi$ and a surjective projection for $\psi$ and be done.  So, my question is, is this $M/M^{\prime\prime}=M^{\prime}/M^{\prime\prime}\bigoplus M/M^{\prime}$ true?  If not, I'd appreciate suggestions for a $\phi$ and a $\psi$ so that the $image(\phi)=kernel(\psi)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M/M''$ is not isomorphic to $M'/M'' \oplus M /M'$ in general. A counterexample is the $\mathbb{Z}$ modules $M'' = 0$, $M = \mathbb{Z}$, $M' = 2 \mathbb{Z}$. Note here they cannot be isomorphic since the left side has no torsion elements but the right side does.

If you want to come up with a simple exact sequence of the kind you're looking for, take $M''=0$, and let $M$ be any torsion module and $M'<M$ any submodule. Of course, you can also come up with cases where $M'' \neq 0$.